# How to set source type for FTP in java

Tags: java, ftp

we use

```
.........
.....
put "C:\Users\rahulsri\Desktop\backup\Zerty\test.CBL" /QSYS.LIB/XYZ.LIB/QSRC.FILE/test.MBR
quote RCMD CHGPFM FILE(XYZ/QSRC) MBR(test) SRCTYPE(CBL) TEXT('test')
.........
```

for file uploading, here **SRCTYPE(CBL)** is for specifying the source type which i also want to specify at my java Code by using FtpClient class so what are the method to set the source type here, or other mean how can we set it.

Comment: FtpClient from `sun.net.ftp`, or from apache-commons-net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`sendCommand`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#sendCommand%28java.lang.String%29) method to send arbitrary commands to the remote server.

```
client.sendCommand("RCMD CHGPFM FILE(XYZ/QSRC) MBR(test) SRCTYPE(CBL) TEXT('test')");
```

From the documentation:

> Sends an FTP command with no arguments to the server, waits for a reply and returns the numerical response code. After invocation, for more detailed information, the actual reply text can be accessed by calling `getReplyString` or `getReplyStrings`.

Comment: can you hint out me for deleting the whole directory's file and directory as well? i am new in this.

Comment: FTP servers typically don't have a "recursive delete" command. You have to descend into the subdirectories and delete the files one by one before you can delete the subdirectory. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931894/ftp-protocol-and-deleting-directories