# FTP How to delete a folder?

Tags: c++, ftp

In my FTP Client application in MFC VC++, I am listing a server's directory files and deleting them successfully. `LIST` and `NLIST` commands work fine in listing the directory files/content.

As well as the files, two folders (which contain files which are not listed) appear on the list which is correct. However, when I pass `DELE` command to these folders, an error is returned and the folders remain. I feel that this is because they are folders.

Below is the `Delete()` function I have implemented:

```
int CFTPClient::Delete(const tstring& strFile) const
{
   ASSERT( !strFile.empty() );
   CReply Reply;
   if( !SendCommand(CCommand::DELE(), strFile, Reply) )
       return FTP_ERROR;
   return SimpleErrorCheck(Reply);
}
```

My question is this: Are there any commands in FTP which remove/delete folders? I am referring to the RFC 959 FTP protocol. `DELE` and `RMD` commands do not work for folders.

Comment: why does `RMD` not work? "This command causes the directory specified in the pathname to be removed as a directory"

Comment: *"an error is returned"* - which error?  Anyway, try DELE on the folders' files first, then RMD on the folders themselves.

Comment: When using RMD and DELE, "521 Error removing directory" and "521 Error deleting file"  appear on WireShark...  NLIST lists the directory files and folders, but the folder contents I can't access ... any ideas how I can access or 'open' the folders somehow?

Answer (score 2):

The `RMD` command can in general remove an empty directory only.

So first, you have to recursively delete the directory contents before issuing the `RMD` command.

See also [FTP Protocol and Deleting Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1931894/850848).

Comment: Yes I am recursively deleting all files in the directory which works fine. However, the two folders are not deleted as DELE does not remove them.

Comment: You have to use `RMD`, not `DELE` on directories. Can you delete the folders using a GUI FTP client?

Comment: I've been using SmartFTP Client but it does not offer the option to delete directory content...do you know any commands which list folder content/files in a directory?

Comment: I cannot try now, but I doubt SmartFTP cannot delete directory recursively. Can you try WinSCP or another FTP client and show us its log? To list directory contents, use `NLST`.

Comment: Yes WinSCP uses LIST to list the directory("\") content and CWD to open the folder or change directory in other words(i.e. CWD \IMAGES). However, when I tried to delete files in the images folder, the same 521 error was thrown in WireShark. DELE does not work either.  Very frustrating. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What happens if you create a fresh new folder and try to delete it?

Comment: What is your FTP server?

Comment: I'll try that now.. my server happens to be a company firmware module that I'm a uploading files to via it's static IP...